# Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
My model and controller
```

Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: value
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: value

My EmailModel

```
 public class EmailModel
{
    [Required,Display(Name= "Name")]
    public string FromName { get; set; }
    [Required, Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string FromEmail { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
}
```

My IdentityConfig.cs

```
 public async Task<bool> SendMailAsync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        //private config set up
        var GmailUsername = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["username"];
        var GmailPasword = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["password"];
        var host = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["host"];
        int port = Convert.ToInt32(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["port"]);

        var from = new MailAddress(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["emailfrom"], "MyBugTracker");

        //Email object set up
        var email = new MailMessage(from, new MailAddress(message.Destination))
        {
            Subject = message.Subject,
            Body = message.Body,
            IsBodyHtml = true,
        };

        //SMTP set up
        using (var smtp = new SmtpClient()
        {
            Host = host,
            Port = port,
            EnableSsl = true,
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(GmailUsername, GmailPasword)

        })
        {
            try
            {
                await smtp.SendMailAsync(email);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                return false;
            }
        };


    }
}
```

This is my AppSettings I'm using a localhost

```
     <appSettings>
  <add key ="username" value="mygmail"/>
  <add key="password" value="myPassword"/>
  <add key="emailfrom" value="s@gmail.com"/>
  <add key="host" value=" smtp.gmail.com"/>
  <add key="port " value="587"/>
</appSettings>
```

This is my error

I try to change the port number to 465 but does not work

Comment: Where abouts in the code does this error occur?

Comment: What is your question? If it's changing a port in the settings file, then what's the code snippet for? Please review [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help the community to be able help you.

Comment: Im a newbie sorry if my question was not so clear, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue comes from the space in the appSettings file for the port key. You have specified 
"port " as a key with a space instead of 
"port". This is why the arguments is out of range when you try to instantiate the SmtpClient. If you change your appSettings and remove the space and leave the code as it is. It Will work.

If this resolves your issue. Please chose this as the ideal answer.